# Analytical approximation for logit-normal-binomial distribution

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation, approximate-integration

As I understand, there is no closed form expression for

$$f(x, \mu, \sigma) = \int_0^1 p^{(x-1)}(1-p)^{n-x-1}\exp\left(-{(\text{logit}(p) -\mu)^2 \over 2\sigma^2}\right)dp.$$

Is it possible to obtain an analytical approximation for this?

Comment: Do you mean "asymptotic"? There are numerous analytic approximations to any continuous function.

Comment: I suppose there must be some that are more computationally efficient/reach small error with a smaller number of terms? I need to insert this as part of a statistical model so a tradeoff between accuracy and efficiency is needed.

Comment: You could use quadrature to evaluate it at many arguments and then do interpolation.

Comment: I suppose that can work. I've never attempted something similar so I had something like a multivariable Taylor series in mind. I guess that theoretical guarantees are irrelevant when there's enough computational power to brute force the approximation and ensure it works over the range of things I care about.

Comment: The theoretical guarantees will be much stronger with an interpolator than with multivariate Taylor series.

Comment: This'll get you going in python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html

Comment: This'll get you going in C++: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/double_exponential/de_tanh_sinh.html

Comment: Do you happen to have a textbook or similar resource that explains why interpolations work? Sorry if it's something obvious. I would gladly accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

- Decide on an interpolator. I suggest a tricubic b-spline, but finding software for this is going to be painful. To understand this interpolant, start in Rainer Kress's *Numerical Analysis* which introduces it in 1D, learn about the bicubic b-splines in 2D, and then you'll be able to understand the tricubic. If you don't like tricubic b-splines, as an alternative, you might also be able to use multivariate Chebyshev series.
- Interpolators require data at a particular geometry of points; figure out what those points are for your given interpolator and then evaluate the integral by quadrature at each point. (For tricubic b-splines it's easy: A uniform grid.) It looks like tanh-sinh quadrature is probably the best for this integral but Gaussian or Gauss-Kronrod will also work fine.

Another alternative is just to use quadrature to evaluate $f$ at any point $(x, \mu, \sigma)$, and ditch the interpolator. This will reduce the speed by a factor of 10 to 100, but since a quadrature takes about 500ns-1$\mu$s, you might not really care.

If you've never done anything like this get ready for some effort shock.